# Bootstrap - Adding sliding menu with scroll Arrows on navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since i have menus more than the container width, i tried to add sliding scroll with arrows, but i couldn't achieve it. First, i couldn't make those menus appear in one row & I couldn't make the menus slide left and right when click the arrows. I tried some css & jquery code. that is also not working. Please help me. Thank in advance. 
**Note:** Please see the fiddle in full screen to understand the issue clearly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chevron-right").on("click", function() {
    alert("click");
    $('.nav').animate({
      left: 100
    }, 'slow');
  })
  $(".chevron-left").on("click", function() {
    alert("click");
    $('.nav').animate({
      left: 100
    }, 'slow');
  })
})
```

```css
.navbar-angle {
  position: relative;
}

.chevron-left {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9;
}

.chevron-right {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/paperindex.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/pi-header-n-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-angle">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse mrgn-btm-0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 5 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 14</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a custom horizontal scroll mechanism for a DOM element, without displaying a scrollbar and binding the scroll left and right to some elements. I assume you want it to work on any device (ideally with ability to swipe on touch devices) and I also assume you want it to work in all browsers, or at least in modern ones.

I don't know how obvious it is to you, but this is a really complex task, especially if you want the custom scroller to feel natural, native, to automatically stop at edges, maybe have a little elasticity in it's animation, etc... So I really don't understand how you assumed asking on SO and getting a custom script would produce a better one than existing plugins/libraries, which have a lot more time invested in their development, with most being heavily tested and production ready.

Speaking of which, I would choose Malihu's [`custom scroller plugin`](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) for the job. Initially designed to scroll images, it's quite powerful and versatile and can be used on any kind of content. However, applying it to your menu is beyond the scope of my answer. ***You*** should do it and, if you run into any trouble, come here and ask a separate question about that problem.

---

I've written the above after initially trying to answer your question (see snippet below), only to realize, when I achieved what you asked for, that the amount of effort required to transform it from a proof of concept into a production ready cross-browser / cross-device script is way too much for a Stack Overflow answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let keepScrolling, 
   scrollBy = 123,
    duration = 123,
    GetWidths = function(selector, i = 0) {
     $(selector).each(function (index) {
        i += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
        });
    return i;
    },
    currentMax = GetWidths('.navbar-angle .navbar-nav > li') - $(window).width();

  function navScrollTo(direction = true) {
    let
      menu = $('.navbar-angle nav'),
      scroller = $('li:first-child', menu),
      current = parseInt(scroller.css("margin-left")),
      checked = Math.max(
       Math.min(
         isNaN(current) ? -scrollBy : current, 
          -scrollBy
          ), 
        scrollBy - currentMax - 102
        ),
      newVal = direction ? checked - scrollBy : checked + scrollBy;
    scroller.animate({
      'margin-left': newVal + 'px'
    }, duration, "linear");
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (keepScrolling) navScrollTo(direction);
    }, duration);
  }
  $('.navbar-angle > i').mousedown(function(e) {
    keepScrolling = true;
    navScrollTo($(e.target).closest('.fa').hasClass('chevron-left'));
  }).mouseup(function(e) {
    keepScrolling = false;
  });
  // in a production env the function below should be throttled
  // with {trailing:true}
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    currentMax = GetWidths('.navbar-angle .navbar-nav > li') - $(window).width()
  })
})
```

```css
.navbar-angle>i {
  display: none;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-angle {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .navbar-angle>i {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #222;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid #080808
  }
  .navbar-angle>i.chevron-left {
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  }
  .navbar-angle>i.chevron-right {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .12);
  }
  .navbar-angle nav {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .12);
  }
  .navbar-angle .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar-angle nav .navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-angle nav .navbar-nav li {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-angle nav li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-angle">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse mrgn-btm-0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 5 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bootstrapPage 14</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Here's [`the fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/j0wqqdu6/) (I prefer it because it allows me to resize the panels - (and it also parses SCSS - which I haven't used here, though)).

---

Apart from this, your are currently loading `jQuery` twice.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei. This is what i exactly wanted & working fine. but, the horizontal scrollbar is appearing and  as i have given max-width to the nav, the menus which are in the outside the nav are not hiding. Please see this, https://html.paperindex.com/sliding-menu.html

Comment: As a general rule, rather than overriding Bootstrap's CSS it is better to add your own classes and style those. Instead of giving `.container-fluid` a fixed width, you should have used `.container`. Also, note the only valid use of nested containers in Bootstrap is a `.container` inside a `.container-fluid`. Lastly, if you want to give your menu's container `overflow-x:hidden` you need to give it sufficient height to accommodate the drop-downs. Last, but not least, you seem to have taken out relevant code from  your [mcve]. I'm afraid I'm not currently available for hire.